# Rails Devise: Render and Update Multiple Model Fields on Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have created a simple Rails app, that uses devise. For logging in and out I use the standard USER model that has email + password. I have a PROFILE model to store all the other details for the user.

I want to create a page where the user can update all their details. Currently getting the following error...

> NoMethodError in UsersController#update
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

[Screenshot of entire error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjdxg.png)

My models look as so...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,  :rememberable, :validatable
             
      has_one :profile
      after_create :create_profile
      attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :description
    
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
    
    end
    
        class Profile < ApplicationRecord
         belongs_to :user
        end
```

View page code looks like...

```
<h1>Account Details</h1>

<p><strong>Email:</strong>    <%= @user.email %></p>
<p><strong>First Name:</strong> <%= @user.profile.first_name %></p>
<p><strong>Last Name:</strong> <%= @user.profile.last_name %></p>

<%= form_for(@user, :as => :user) do |field| %>
<p>
<%= field.label :email  %>
<%= field.text_field :email %>
</p>
<%= fields_for @user.profile do |profile| %>
  <p>
    <%= profile.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= profile.text_field :first_name %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= field.submit "Update" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and the Controller looks like

```
    Class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def new
        build_resource({})
        resource.build_profile
        respond_with self.resource
    end

    def create
        super
    end

    def edit
        super
    end

    def update
        @user = current_user
    end

    def show
        @user = current_user
    end

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u|
     u.permit(:email, :password, [profile_attributes: [ :first_name, :last_name]])
}
end 

end
```

I can't get this form to render and update the models. I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- move `configure_permitted_parameters` and corresponding
  `before_action` to the `ApplicationController`
- delete UsersController, looks like you don't need it
- change devise permitted parameters a bit: `u.permit(:email, :password, profile_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name])`

Comment: Moved parameters as advised. Still needed the Users controller. Not really sure why.

Comment: I don't remember exactly. It was a routing error saying that UsersController could not be found... even though I had removed all reference. On relection maybe I should have destroyed it properly via a rails d controller user command.

Comment: @JimmyD, maybe you forgot to remove it from `routes.rb`?

Comment: I definitely removed it from the routes.rb file... but as I created it via a rails command (g controller) I'm thinking that I should have removed it via the rails destroy command. What I actually did was just delete the file manually

Comment: @JimmyD, it should be enough to delete the file. If you want, you can remove it again and create a new question on SO (with full error trace and routes.rb), I'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

delete UsersController and

in application_controller

```
class ApplicationController<ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with::exception
  before_action:configure_permitted_parameters,if::devise_controller? 

def check_is_admin
 if current_user.is_admin
  return true
 else
   redirect_to roots_path,notice:"page looking for sign_in"
 end
end

private

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
new_user_session_path
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
root_path
end

protected
def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up,keys:[:first_name, :last_name])
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update,keys:[:first_name, :last_name])
end

end
```

you can change path depend on your use....